# Chess Knight, Available movement

Tags: python, matrix

```
# Input coordinates for position, convert to integers.
start = [int(input("x: ")),int(input("y: "))] 

# Available moves for Knight ( 3 steps like **L**)
available = [
    [start[0]-1,start[1]-2],
    [start[0]-2,start[1]-1],
    [start[0]+1,start[1]-2],
    [start[0]+2,start[1]-1],
    [start[0]-1,start[1]+2],
    [start[0]-2,start[1]+1],
    [start[0]+1,start[1]+2],
    [start[0]+2,start[1]+1]
]
```

For each row horizontally print (1-8)  and for each column character **"O"**.If coordinates**(x,y)** are in the available list print **M**. Second **if** checks where on chessboard moves are possible.

```
used_positions = 0

for y in range(8):
    print(y+1,end=" ")0-8  #  y+1 will start from 1-8 and not 0- 8       
    
letters = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']


    for x in range(8):
        chr = "O"
        if [x+1,y+1] == start:
            chr = "S"
        if [x+1,y+1] in available:
            used_positions+=1
            chr = "M"
        print(chr,end="") # skips newline
    print() # after every column  newline
print(end="  ") # newline, 2 whitespaces
for l in letters:
    print(l,end="") # prints letters

print() # newline

print("Possible positions:",used_positions) # prints how many positions are possible
print(available,end='') # prints available positions in same line
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement this in a list comprehension that filters out the 'out-of-board' positions:

```
def knightMoves(x,y):
    return [(x+dx,y+dy)
            for h,v   in [(1,2),(2,1)]                     # magnitudes
            for dx,dy in [(h,v),(h,-v),(-h,v),(-h,-v)]     # directions
            if x+dx in range(1,9) and y+dy in range(1,9) ] # in-board
```

output:

```
knightMoves(4,5)
[(5, 7), (5, 3), (3, 7), (3, 3), (6, 6), (6, 4), (2, 6), (2, 4)]

knightMoves(8,8)
[(7, 6), (6, 7)]
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the knight moves in `L`. So, the -1 and -2 is for following this way. For example:

⬜
⬜

2 steps down, and 1 step left.

Comment: Yes, I know that. Thanks. Only what I could not understand why in available is numbers -1, -2, 1 and - 1 and that is actually all possible movements like u said **L**.

Comment: @Asterix Those numbers -1, -2 and the others, are for calculate the possible movements. So, for example, if your input is x=3 and y=3, and the first item in the available list is [start[0]-1,start[1]-2], the new position will be calculated like this: x=3-1=2 and y=3-2=1, so first possible position will be x=2, y=1.

Comment: Yeah I have understood all the code know , thanks for assistance

Answer (score 0):

E.g. my input was **x=2, y=2**. Four possible positions: **[4,1], [3,4], [4,3],[1,4]** which is marked as **M*.* Every x and y is calculated in available positions. E.g. [start[0]-1,start[1]-2], 2-1 = 1 (x = 1) , 2-2 = 0 (y) , [1,0].

```
1 OOOMOOOO
2 OSOOOOOO
3 OOOMOOOO
4 MOMOOOOO
5 OOOOOOOO
6 OOOOOOOO
7 OOOOOOOO
8 OOOOOOOO
  ABCDEFGH
Possible positions: 4
[[1, 0], [0, 1], [3, 0], [4, 1], [1, 4], [0, 3], [3, 4], [4, 3]]
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31105058)

Comment: @GinoMempin, Greetings Gino. Please check if I corrected my question with more details  precisely. I also changed my answer as you said. Thank you.